# Mix Static MoXy and Dynamic Moxy

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I am trying to check one concept of mixing Static moxy and Dynamic moxy.
I have two schemas.

1. One is the base schema(emp.xsd) which is not going to change often,so I used the static Moxy and generated classes for it, added those classes to classpath, and used these concrete types(e.g. SearchManager) in my program.
2. Another is the derived schema(Manager.xsd) which is going to change often, so I plan to use Dynamic Moxy to generate the dynamic types on the fly.I am facing some issues mentioned below.

Is this kind of mix of static and dynamic moxy possible?

code snippet:

### emp.xsd(parent schema):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:emp="Employee:2:0" targetNamespace="Employee:2:0"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="2.0">

    <xsd:element name="searchManager" type="emp:SearchManager" />

    <xsd:complexType name="SearchManager">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CompanyName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="objects" type="emp:Employee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:complexType name="Employee">

        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="emp:Organization">
                <xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element name="EmpId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Projects">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="emp:Organization"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Organization">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Abstract base class </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### manager.xsd (Child schema):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema targetNamespace="Manager:1:0" xmlns:emp="Employee:2:0"
    xmlns:manager="Manager:1:0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="1.0">
    <!-- schema imports -->
    <xs:import namespace="Employee:2:0" schemaLocation="emp.xsd" />

    <xs:complexType name="Manager">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Definition of class Employee
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="emp:Employee">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="teamSize" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="project1" type="manager:Project1"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="Project1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="manager:Developement">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="type" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Developement">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Abstract base class for an Development
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="emp:Projects"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### Java code for marshalling and unmarshalling:

```java
public class XMLToJSONUsingBaseClasses {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream xsdInputStream;
    try {
        xsdInputStream = new FileInputStream("Manager.xsd");
        DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, new MyEntityResolver(), null, null);

        FileInputStream xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream("manager.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStream);

    }catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

manager.xml

```xml
<emp:searchManager xmlns:emp="Employee:2:0"
    xmlns:manager="Manager:1:0">
    <CompanyName>Test</CompanyName>
    <objects xmlns:ns2="Manager:1:0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:Manager">
        <EmpId>123456</EmpId>
        <teamSize>10</teamSize>
        <project1>
            <type>1</type>
        </project1>
    </objects>
</emp:searchManager>
```

exception.

```java
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: employee._2._0.SearchManager cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicEntityImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.unmarshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.convertSAXException(SAXUnmarshaller.java:996)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:585)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: employee._2._0.SearchManager cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicEntityImpl
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.ValuesAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(ValuesAccessor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping.setAttributeValueInObject(XMLDirectMapping.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectUnmarshalContext.setAttributeValue(ObjectUnmarshalContext.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.setAttributeValue(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.endElement(XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.endElement(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:1026)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parseEvent(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:895)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I am also facing an issue something like this where I need to use both static and dynamic POJO classes so wanted to confirm with you. Did you report this bug? Also, what workaround did you take to solve this? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

We do not currently support mixing static and dynamic in that way.  Could you please use the link below to enter an enhancement request for your use case:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: Hi, is there any workaround now for this issue? Please provide some insight into this.